# PUT request to WCF Rest service using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

hi i have this code on my server :

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "createinvoice", Method = "PUT")]
    public Invoice CreateInvoice(Invoice instance)
    {
        // TODO: Add the new instance of SampleItem to the collection
        try
        {

            string icode = instance.InvoiceCode;
            

            return new Invoice() {InvoiceCode = icode };
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        
    }
```

Now this on my client side:

```
var instance = {};
    instance.InvoiceCode = "INV0004";
    //instance.AmountPaid = 1000;
    alert (JSON.stringify(instance));
    $.ajax({
        //cache:false,
        url : 'http://localhost/Mobile/POS/createinvoice/',
        data: JSON.stringify(instance),
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        async:false,
        success: function(msg){
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception){
            alert("error "+ jqXHR.status);
        }
    });
```

Now based on what i've read PUT method doesn't append the data on the URL itself. Now everytime i  run it using firebug i see a 404 not Found error. I practically new at this so i don't really have a clue as of the moment. the get method is quite easy compared to this. Can you help me figure out what's wrong? THANK YOU.

## update

i viewed the xhr on firebug and this was part of the response ( in html)

```
<p xmlns="">Endpoint not found. Please see the <a rel="help-page" href="http://localhost/Mobile/POS/help">service help page</a> for constructing valid requests to the service.</p>
```

If i'm reading it correctly it says i have something wrong on actual request i'm making? and that either the format is wrong?

## end of update

Comment: Not the issue here, but the server doesn't send `json` and you're expecting to get `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: oops sorry forgot to put the responseformat and requestformat. see i've already added the responseformat and requestformat but still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,UriTemplate = "createinvoice", Method = "PUT")]
public Invoice CreateInvoice(Invoice instance){
   ***
}
```

---

**EDIT**

according to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) `put` is not supported by all browsers.

> **type**
>
> Default: 'GET' The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"),
> default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and
> DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all
> browsers.

Comment: i've already added that. i just forgot to add it on my question. But still it doesn't work. It the client side triggering this problem?

Comment: is your URL correct? did you try it directly on browser? expecting something like this, `/Mobile/POS/*****.svc/createinvoice/`

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service

Comment: @MadurikaWelivita yes, itried it "Method not allowed. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service."

Comment: so you mean i should change the type from PUT to GET? but if i change it to GET it will append the data being passed on the actual url. which will make {"InvoiceCode":"INV0004"} to ?{%22InvoiceCode%22:%22INV0004%22}

Comment: That's why we have `POST` option.

Comment: Also itried it on chrome and firefox i still have the same problem. Can the problem be on the web.config? is there a pre-requirement in setting up put methods?

Comment: okay, i changed it to post. but still my problem never faded. it states endpoint not found. any ideas where would the problem be?

Comment: @Dreyfus15: you can verify that PUT verb is added in the extension mapping for the .svc

Comment: @MadurikaWelivita how can i do that? i'm relatively new at wcf services.

Comment: first try to access the service directly on the browser.

Comment: i have a registered a route for service1.svc and named it POS so if i access http://localhost/Mobile/POS/help it would appear but if http://localhost/Mobile/POS only it states endpoint not found.

Comment: oops its not service1.svc just service1.cs